# Python Appending Via Numpy

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to calculate standard deviation for a numpy array i made. I am having issues in my loop when I try to append the df3 to df2 arrays. The error I keep getting is

" AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'append' "

```
b = np.random.randint(30, 100, size=(10,20))
import numpy as np
df2 = np.empty
df3 = np.empty 
index = 0
for i in b:
    df1 = b[index,:]
    df2 = df1.std()
    df3 = df3.append(df2)
    index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually way more efficient to initialize a zero array, rather than append to an array in a loop. I would avoid doing that at all times unless it was absolutely necessary.

Since you know the size of your output, you can initialize a zero array quite easily.

```
import numpy as np

b = np.random.randint(30, 100, size=(10,20))
stds = np.zeros(10)
for i in range(b.shape[0]):
    row = b[i,:]
    stds[i] = row.std()
```

But in fact you don't even have to do that. Better yet use `np.apply_along_axis`.

```
def get_std(arr):
    return arr.std()

stds = np.apply_along_axis(get_std, 1, b)
```

Does this give you what you're after?